# Editing an ELF executable to reduce it's size

Tags: linux, size, executable, elf

I'm trying to drop a C program down to a size < 1kb. I'm getting close, but I'm stuck on editing my ELF executable. My program, `main.c` looks like:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>

void _start() {
    const char msg [] = "Hello World!";
    syscall(SYS_write, 0, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
    syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
```

I'm compiling it with

`gcc -nostdlib -s -O3 -o main main.c /usr/lib/path/to/libc.a`

Then I `strip` it. But If I did an objdump on it before stripping it I see

main:     file format elf64-x86-64

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000400158 l    d  .note.gnu.build-id     0000000000000000 .note.gnu.build-id
0000000000400180 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000400214 l    d  .eh_frame_hdr  0000000000000000 .eh_frame_hdr
0000000000400238 l    d  .eh_frame      0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000601000 l    d  .tbss  0000000000000000 .tbss
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 main.c
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000
00000000004001d0 g     F .text  0000000000000026 syscall
0000000000000000 g       .tbss  0000000000000004 errno
0000000000400203 g       .text  0000000000000000 __syscall_error_1
0000000000400180 g     F .text  0000000000000048 _start
0000000000000000 g       .tbss  0000000000000004 __libc_errno
0000000000400200 g     F .text  0000000000000013 __syscall_error
0000000000601000 g       .eh_frame      0000000000000000 __bss_start
0000000000601000 g       .eh_frame      0000000000000000 _edata
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000601000 g       .eh_frame      0000000000000000 _end
```

It seems like there's some stuff I can remove to manually reduce the size of the executable? **note**: I know this is not something I'd *actually* do, but I'm simply trying to remove any boilerplate existing.

What would I remove from the executable, `main`, to reduce it's size? And how could I do that?

side note: I've already read [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free) and [this](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) article. No need to link them. I am purposely choosing to stay with C

Comment: I don't understand: are you wanting to reduce the size of the executable code or the size of the executable file?  $ ls -l test or $ size test; check one.

Comment: I guess, you're not happy with `-Os`…

Comment: Then there is the option to compile to 32 bit code.

Comment: @OldestSoftwareGuy I'm trying to reduce the overall size of the executable file as small as I possibly can. I know it's not good to actually edit and take out sections of an executable, but I'd like to know regardless how I can do that from the command line

Comment: You can gain a few bytes with `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -Qn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple stuff

You can remove quite a few useless bits with:

- `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -Qn`;
- using a custom linker script `-rlinker_script`.

I get a working binary of 992 bytes with this (after strip).

### Linker script

Let's look at the sections (before stripping):

```
[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
     Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
[ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
     0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
[ 1] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             0000000000400120  00000120
     0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
[ 2] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000400150  00000150
     0000000000000090  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
[ 3] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         00000000004001e0  000001e0
     0000000000000048  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
[ 4] .tbss             NOBITS           0000000000601000  00000228
     0000000000000004  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     4
[ 5] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000003e7
     0000000000000044  0000000000000000           0     0     1
[ 6] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00000228
     0000000000000168  0000000000000018           7     6     8
[ 7] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00000390
     0000000000000057  0000000000000000
```

From program header 5, everything is stripped but we gave two comparatively useless sections which are not stripped: `.note.gnu.build-id` and `.eh_frame`. The `.eh_frame` was disabled in the compiler but some `.eh_frame` is contributed from the static libc.

We can completely get rid of the `.eh_frame` and `.note.gnu.build-id` sections with a custom linker script (`gcc -T linker_script`).

First, we get the default linker script:

```
gcc test.c -Wl,--verbose
```

We remove those lines:

```
.eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
.eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
.note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
```

and modify this line:

```
/DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*)  *(.note.gnu.build-id) *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) *(.eh_frame) *(.eh_frame.*)  }
```

I get 664 bytes using this.

### Additional options

Other solutions for a reduced size:

- optimize for size (`-Os`);
- 32 bit compilation (`-m32`).

With all of this, I get a binary with 760 bytes without the custom linker script and 488 bytes with the modified linker script.

### Get rid of `errno`

There are quite few "useless" things remaining (such as `errno` handling and the TLS) that could be removed.

```
[Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
[ 1] .text             PROGBITS        080480a0 0000a0 00008e 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 2] .tbss             NOBITS          08049130 000130 000004 00 WAT  0   0  4
[ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000257 000027 00      0   0  1
[ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 000130 0000d0 10      5   4  4
[ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000200 000057 00      0   0  1
```

(Everything beginning with section 3 is stripped.)

By writing our own syscall code we could get rid of `errno` handling. We would remove:

- 4 bytes of `.symtab`;
- `errno` related instructions.

But doing this involves using (inline) assembly.

Comment: is `-rlinker_script` a linker flag or compiler flag? I've attempted both with `-rbarebones.lds` and `-Wl,-rbarebones.lds` but both resolve to an error. I tried the linker flag `-Wl,-Tbarebones.lds` which ended up telling me there's a redefinition of `_start`

Comment: I know you edited out that previous code, but do you know what references I can go to in order to understand what was there? I'd like to read up on what you edited out

Comment: I fixed the linker script which was broken.

Comment: Super useful answer! Thanks so much, my binary is crazy small now and I also know how to look into linker scripts and start learning about them.